# Is it possible to dynamically add ag-grid localisations?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using the `AgGridModule` Angular wrapper of the `ag-grid` framework. My application is an Angular AOT application which handles localisation using the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) library (which dynamically loads translation data files on page load, for the currently selected language). This means that translations are only available asynchronously. As such I cannot just set the `localeText` property in `gridOptions` ([as recommended](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/)) since I don't have the texts before generating the grid.

Does anyone know how to handle this scenario? Ideally I would just assign an RxJS `Observable` to the `localeText` property, which would send the appropriate texts object when ready, but this does not seem to work currently.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by providing your own `localeTextFunc`. That function takes the key from the grid and uses a translate function (ngx-translate in our case) outside of the grid for doing the translation. If no match is found, then the default value should be returned (which is the English value for the grid, the grids default language).

```
this.gridOptions = {
  localeTextFunc: (key: string, defaultValue: string) => {
    // look the value up. using the ngx translate service
    const data = this.translate.instant(key);
    return data === key ? defaultValue : data;
  }
};
```

Inject `TranslateService` as translate from '@ngx-translate/core' to use the synchronous `translate.instant()` method. But make sure the translations have been loaded before calling instant mthod.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't see how this can work. `translate.get()` returns an asynchronous observable stream, so the return in the subscription closure should not have any effect in the `localeTextFunc` function.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you pointing it out. Instead of `translate.get()` we can use `translate.instant()` which returns the instant translated value of a key and this method is synchronous.

Comment: `instant` might be useful, indeed, but is not going to give the right value if the translation files haven't yet been loaded.

Comment: You can preload translations using `.use()` method but `.use()` is async and might need to use `APP_INITIALIZER` function in your `AppModule` like shown in this github issue - https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517#issuecomment-299637956 or you will need to write your own custom synchronous translation loader.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think this is a bit of drawback of ag-grid. I'm going to stick with my current (imperfect) solution of assigning translations to a local object (which the `localeTextFunc` looks at every time) and attempting to refresh the grid when translation have been loaded to force ag-grid to call the function again (so far I haven't got this to work for the grouping column).